# How do I mimic a Carousel refresh of data upon a successful jQuery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a div that contains a handful of articles. When the user clicks the next button I want the existing articles to slide left and have the next page of articles slide in to replace them.

[image]

Im looking to have my results slide in left if the user clicks the > next link or slide in right if the user clicks the < prev link. (sort of like a carousel)

Here's a working example of the slideDown animation.

```
//Fetch the new result set.
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/_WhatsNew',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/json',

    //The request was a success. Repopulate the div with new result set.
    success: function (data) {
        $("#Content").empty();
        $(data).hide().appendTo('#Content').slideDown();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Fail');
    }
});
```

Is it possible to do this in a carousel like manner?

Comment: Take a look at [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery UI slide effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/):

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#Content')
        .hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 400, function () {
            $(this)
                .html(result)
                .show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 400);
        });
}
```

Simply include the `jquery-ui-1.8.11.js` script to your page and enjoy:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```